# Is there any other manga artist/s whose style is like CLAMP's?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

Is there any other manga artist/s (famous or not-so-famous) who caters anime or manga like CLAMP's style?

I'm talking about the *cross-over style* or the re-using of anime characters from one of their manga creations to another and the diverging of their stories. CLAMP is known for that style and it was loosely defined as the "Clamp Universe" or "Clamp Multiverse".

If there is, then who is that manga artist/s and what are those anime/manga that manga artist/s created, and if possible, a preview of the anime's/manga's plot?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to know what manga artists (other than CLAMP) have cross-overs or what artists have similar drawing style to CLAMP?

Comment: Manga artists who have cross-overs and have that same "multiverse" style like CLAMP's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Osamu Tezuka, perhaps ?

In his mangas, the same characters would appear in different roles. Given the ammount of work he produce, it's not a big surprise he could do that. Don't think it was intensive like CLAMP, but was well used, in specific situations.

Tezuka had his [Star System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Tezuka%27s_Star_System), and his characters would appear in many stories, sometimes without a formal reference (not being identified as such).

Examples:

Black Jack made some apparitions in Astro Boy... Astro Boy made many apparitions in Black Jack and in other mangas.

Comment: Were their stories similar to CLAMP's that had plots collided with each other?

Answer (score 4):

Since the title mentioned "manga" but your description said "anime or manga", I'll just put it here. I'm conflicted because this one across many medias (Light Novel, Anime, Manga, Visual Novel).

**[Type-Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-Moon)** (Fate series, Kara no Kyoukai, Tsukihime, etc) has its famous **[Nasuverse](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Franchise/Nasuverse)**.

> The universe of the writings of TYPE-MOON's scenario director, [Kinoko Nasu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinoko_Nasu). It's made up of several "sub-universes" ("franchises" that share characters) that take place in the same world with the same rules, but interestingly enough, seldom obviously cross over.
>   ~tvtropes

There's also this image of  [Nasuverse Character Chart](http://images34.fotosik.pl/64/031a310f6bfa47cd.jpg).

The difference with CLAMP is, while CLAMP likes to make the character clearly has an appearance in other series, Nasuverse isn't like that, and that's why, above, it's described as

> ...take place in the same world with the same rules, but interestingly enough, **seldom obviously** cross over. ~tvtropes

So don't expect to see something so obvious like when Syaoran and Sakura of TRC appear in XXXHolic (that even turns out their plot is related). From what I understand, Nasuverse heavily put its chain between series around its concept of magic, mage, and supernatural being. There's some character related, but still it's not like they appear like, how Sumeragi Clan of Tokyo Babylon involved heavily in X. As far as I know, their character relation is 'implied', like, X from Y series is teacher in School Q, and 'coincidentally', in B series, A is student in School Q.

For all the preview of anime and manga, you can see it in the tvtropes link I gave above. Almost all of them has magic as one of the story element, which also poses as one of its universe's chain. For deeper explanation of the universe, you can see its [analysis page, still in the same site.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Analysis/Nasuverse)

CMIIW.